# Accessing X509 Certificate Extension Fields in OpenSSL

Tags: .net, openssl, certificate

I'm trying for hours now to access Extension fields of X509 Certficates. I'm using the .net Wrapper classes for OpenSSL.

This is how I can access the data:

```
byte[] data = MySSLCertificate.Extensions[0].Data
```

I tried casting it to an ASCII Encoded String but I keep getting weird symbols:

```
"0p?!test@hsm..."
```

insted of:

```
"email:test@hsm..."
```

Anyone an idea on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asn.1), X.509 and related data objects including extensions are encoded in this way. Think of it like a "binary XML" encoding for data interchange.

You can use OpenSSL directly to see (most) of the ASN.1 structure of a cert with:

```
openssl asn1parse -in mycert.pem -inform PEM
```

but [`dumpasn1`](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/#standards) is better (DER input required)

```
openssl x509 -in mycert.pem -inform PEM -out mycert.der -outform DER
dumpasn1 -adilt mycert.der
```

The extensions will appear as a set of SEQUENCEs after the RSA data. See also my answer to this question on SO: [ASN.1 Octet Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299201/asn-1-octet-strings)

Comment: Do you know if there's an API for .net available for this? I'm using OpenSSL.net right now, and there is stuff like "OpenSSL.Core.Asn1String" but I can't get it to produce any useful results since there is no documentation whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [OpenSSL.NET](http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/) wrapper classes, then I surmise that you develop in .NET. Then, you have all the standard .NET classes available, including [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.aspx) and its updated version [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx), which will happily decode your certificates and let you explore their [extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509extension.aspx).

X.509 parsing is complex because each extension is a structure with its own rules. OpenSSL (the C library) includes some code to process *some* extensions (not all of them), but it is unclear whether the .NET wrapper for OpenSSL provides access to these functions. In any case, the point of OpenSSL.NET is to let you run cryptographic algorithms without using the Windows/.NET framework for *private keys* (because it can be cumbersome at times); however, certificates contain only *public keys* and these are handled just fine by .NET classes.

You could also learn [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) and [decode things yourself](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280). It will take you some considerable effort, but you will gain some considerable knowledge in the process.

Comment: So this sounds nice, but it doesn't seem to work in my case: "The X509Extension class can be used to create extensions that are associated with a certificate but are not part of a certificate as issued by a certification authority (CA)." Latter is exactly what I want to do..

Comment: The `X509Certificate2.Extensions` property _will_ return a collection of `X509Extension` object which describe the extensions _as found in the certificate_. Try it ! (.NET documentation is known to be occasionally misleading and poorly written)

Comment: Oh okay, I was rather confused when I did not find the Extensions Collection in the .Net documentation for the X509Certificate. Thanks for your help